# can I use same json file of google vision api for OCR conversion in two programs?

Tags: python, json, google-vision

I am doing 2 different projects which needs OCR conversion. I have generated just one json file. can i use the same json file for my both the projects?

Comment: Have you tried using it for both projects...got any issues...?

Comment: I tried using one of the JSON files to other project, the account got banned permanently.